# What does this strange error mean?

Tags: c++, error-handling

I'm writing this program and when I build it, it runs OK.But when I turn the debugger I get this message:

---

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 
In ntdll!LdrWx86FormatVirtualImage  
() (C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll)
```

---

```
 #0 7788E3C6 ntdll!
 LdrWx86FormatVirtualImage() 
 (C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll:??) #1 ?? ?? () (??:??)
```

---

Could you tell me what these errors mean?

Comment: Segmentation fault, a memory error

Comment: What is the call it is failing on?

Comment: You might need to enable including debugging information, that should be in the compiler options.

Comment: This is not a programming question. There is no code.

Comment: Without the code or some debug info we may only guess. You might also check here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault.

Answer (score 0):

It's a segmentation fault.

Probable culprit is passing an invalid pointer around (for example, a buffer that is too small) or trying to deference a null pointer.